# AngularJS directive timing issue

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to figure out the order of operations here, and I'm obviously failing.

I'm trying to implement a jquery image gallery plugin as a directive. The plugin takes a set of images, uses $.load to load them into the DOM, and then upon completion creates a nice gallery.

You can see my example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/KU0lxuoRE5l6rYOAL50A?p=preview). If you click "Load Images", it will pull 20 images from Flickr. What I'd like to have happen is, on load, the $.gridnav function is called. I am demonstrating that functionality when you click "Display GridNav", but obviously don't want that second button click as a requirement.

Now, my directive sits outside of my ng-repeat which is bound to the property getting set on successful callback from flickr. So I understand why it's not getting called again, I'm just not sure what to do to make this function as I'd like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure how `gridnav` is supposed to work, so I'm not sure if this works fully, but what about calling `gridnav` anytime the array changes? You can pass the array into the directive via the view and then `$watch` the vale on the scope inside the directive.

HTML:

```html
<div class="well clearfix giftCardList tj_container" id="giftCardContainer"
     gridnav="giftCards">
  ...
```

JS:

```javascript
link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
  // watch for the value passed in to gridnav attribute to change
  $scope.$watch(attrs.gridnav, function(value){
    // don't do anything unless there's actually a value
    if (!value) return;
    // once it's changed, call gridnav on the next loop
    $timeout(function() {
      $(element).gridnav({
        rows: 1,
        navL: '#giftCard_prev',
        navR: '#giftCard_next',
        type: {
          mode: 'disperse',
          speed: 400,
          easing: '',
          factor: '',
          reverse: ''
        }
      }, 0);
    }, true);
  });
}
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/lMYvIJEkEPRAaNIAuNvF?p=preview